# Table not found error in h2 using hibernate3

Tags: java, sql-server, h2, in-memory-database, hibernate3

I am newbie to h2 database.i created the sessionfactory like below.

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/selva;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.selva.meetinghall.domain.My</value>  
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>




            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

My.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="my")
@Repository
public class My implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1798070786993154670L;
     @Id
     @Column(name ="Id")
     private int id;
     @Column(name ="Name")
     private String name;
    //getter and setter
}
```

Dao :

```
Session session=sessionfactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
    My my=new My();
    my.setId(1);
    my.setName("selva");
    session.save(my);
    tx.commit();
```

I got the error like below.

```
Hibernate: insert into my (Name, Id) values (?, ?)
2015-01-20 18:41:02,911 WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions:77 - SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02
2015-01-20 18:41:02,911 ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions:78 - Table "MY" not found; SQL statement:
insert into my (Name, Id) values (?, ?) [42102-185]
2015-01-20 18:41:02,913 ERROR org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions:301 - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.selva.meetinghall.domain.My]
```

The above code works for mssql persistent database.But does not work in h2 database.What's wrong with my approach?
Is Querying is different for inmemory and persistent databse?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Have you created the table in your h2 db?

Comment: It's clearly saying " Table "MY" not found; SQL statement:" . Please check MY table is present in DB or not.

Comment: Yes,I created.It's their.I checked via browser console